# Finding unique characters from a table field for all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to find the number of distinct character used in the field having multiple rows.

For example, if there are two rows having data like `abcd` and `eaafg*` then distinct character used are `abcdefg*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
INSERT INTO @temp (txt)
VALUES ('abcd3'), ('abcdefg*')

SELECT disword = (
SELECT DISTINCT dt.ch
FROM (
 SELECT ch = SUBSTRING(t.mtxt, n.number + 1, 1) 
 FROM [master].dbo.spt_values n
 CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT mtxt = (
   SELECT txt
   FROM @temp
   FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
  )
 ) t
 WHERE [type] = N'p'
  AND number <= LEN(mtxt) - 1
) dt
FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
)
```

---

Example (edited):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @temp TABLE (txt VARCHAR(8000))

INSERT INTO @temp (txt)
VALUES ('abcd'), ('abcdefg*'), (REPLICATE('-', 8000)), (REPLICATE('+', 8000))

DECLARE @t TABLE (i BIGINT)

DECLARE 
      @i BIGINT = 1
    , @l BIGINT = (
        SELECT SUM(LEN(txt))
        FROM @temp 
    )

WHILE (@i <= @l) BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @t (i) 
    VALUES (@i), (@i+1), (@i+2), (@i+3), (@i+4), (@i+5), (@i+6), (@i+7), (@i+8), (@i+9)
    SELECT @i += 10

END

SELECT disword = (
    SELECT DISTINCT dt.ch
    FROM (
        SELECT ch = SUBSTRING(t.mtxt, n.i, 1) 
        FROM @t n
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT mtxt = (
                SELECT txt
                FROM @temp
                FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
            )
        ) t
    ) dt
    FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
)
```

---

Have a look a t this solution -

```
SELECT 
      dt.ch
    , cnt = COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT ch = SUBSTRING(t.mtxt, n.i, 1)  
    FROM @t n
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT mtxt = (
            SELECT txt
            FROM @temp
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ) t
) dt
WHERE dt.ch != ''
GROUP BY dt.ch
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are questions that may refer to what you are asking:

[How do I get distinct characters of string column in mssql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923830/howto-get-distinct-characters-of-string-column-in-mssql)

and

[SQL: how to get all the distinct characters in a column, across all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925767/sql-how-to-get-all-the-distinct-characters-in-a-column-across-all-rows)

Answer (score 0):

With tallys:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (s NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES ('abcd'), ('abcdefg*')

;WITH tally AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) i
FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t1(n)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t2(n))

SELECT 
(       SELECT DISTINCT sb
        FROM    tally
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT SUBSTRING(s, i, 1) sb FROM @t ) ca
        WHERE   sb <> ''
FOR     XML PATH(N'') , TYPE , ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
```